# Installing gems in a Rails "application template"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have built a Rails "application template" to generate a Rails app with some common gems and configuration pre-installed. The template invokes some generators that need gems installed to work, which has caused me problems when running it on a fresh machine that doesn't have any gems installed besides `bundler` and `rails`. For example, trying to generate a model will fail because it wants `sqlite3`, which is in the Gemfile but not yet installed.

I've tried to solve this by either putting the generators inside an `after_bundle` block, or calling `run "bundle install"` before invoking them. With either of those strategies, I get the following odd error:

> Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? can't activate sqlite3 (~> 1.3.6), already activated sqlite3-1.4.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (LoadError)

What's the proper way to make gems from the generated Gemfile available for the template to use?

[Here is the template.](https://github.com/CSC322-Grinnell/rails_starter_kit/blob/6874f23b8f940ce0b969e7f4da238beaef2bdb84/template.rb)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use "bundle exec" so that the correct gems are loaded based on your Gemfile.

```
bundle exec rails g model MyModel
```

Comment: The commands are being called from within the template (which is Ruby code) using Rails' [generator DSL](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#generate) and other [command DSLs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html#rails-command-command-options), so there is nowhere to invoke `bundler exec`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `run` command to do this for your template. For example, if you're installing and running Rubocop, you can do:

```
gem "rubocop"
gem "rubocop-rails"

run "bundle install"
run "bundle exec rubocop -A"
run "bundle exec rubocop --auto-gen-config"
```